# Valgrind fatal error, running on Slitaz

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

I've installed valgrind-3.9.0 on linux Slitaz-2.6.37 (32bit) booted on virtualbox but when i try to use it on a C program (any a.out file), i encounter this error:

```
==29012== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29012== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Sewrd
==29012== Using Valgrnd-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29012== Command: a.out
==29012==

valgrind: Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind: which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind: cannot be set up. Details of the redirection are:
valgrind: 
valgrind: A must-be-redirected function
valgrind: whose name matches the pattern:    strlen
valgrind: in an object with soname matching:  ld-linux.so.2
valgrind: was not found whilst processing
valgrind: symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux.so.2
valgrind:
valgrind: Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind: package on this machine. (2, long term): ask the packagers
valgrind: for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind: stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind: that exports the above-named function using the standards
valgrind: calling conventions for this platform. The package you need
valgrind: to intall for fix (1) is called
valgrind:
valgrind:   On Debian, Ubuntu:         libc6-dbg
valgrind:   On SuSe, openSuSe, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and Valgrind but it seems that i need a specific package. This error does not report after which name the package is labeled on my distro (Slitaz).
Slitaz does not have the apt-get command nor it's in my intensions to install it (if possible).

I tried to use, with superuser privileges, the command "tazpkg get-install " with any possible combination of libc6-dbg and glibc...
I' ve already searched for a solution on the web without any result. Thanks for your time and attention

Comment: You might want to ask the Slitaz developers about this error... They probably removed debug information from the ld.so file but don't provide a separate debuginfo package. You could ask them to either provide a debuginfo package or to keep debug information in the ld.so.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I started a thread on the Slitaz forum. Currently i'm still in need of a solution. I will update this thread as i find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on `ubuntu 12.04.`
Found that the issue is with the debug symbols and the dependent libraries available on the machine are stripped off the debug symbols.
When i run valgrind on a test program i saw kind of same error. So i did the following.

1. Found out all the libraries (so files) required for the program to run (using ldd).
2. Ran file command to see if the debug symbols are stripped.
3. Checked which package is bringing in that library (dpkg -S).
4. Searched for all the packages which has their name or part of their name as the package name we found in step 3. Intention was to find the debug symbols package (which was stripped out from the actual library).
5. Install the packages containing the corresponding debug symbols.
   For example:

   libc6 package has stripped version of libraries. So i had to install 
             libc6-dbg which brings in the debug symbols.

Comment: Eh... valgrind tells that it is `libc6-dbg` (see last lines in error message). So instead of all your steps - it was better to just read error message more carefully :-)